# TaskDialogIndirect: how to set multi-line buttons

Tags: winapi, taskdialog

TaskDialogIndirect API has the [structure to describe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/commctrl/ns-commctrl-_taskdialog_button) each button. As I see by test on Windows 10, button caption cannot be multi-line (LF or CR LF separated), it will be not rendered OK. Only last line from multi-line string is shown. Can I set multi-line button caption?

Comment: Possible alternative: use command-links (`TDF_USE_COMMAND_LINKS`), which do support multi-line text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. This API does not support multiline button captions.